# Make a cookie last longer than a session

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript to set a cookie but it sets the expire to `session` rather than the date specified

```
  var d1 = new Date (),
  d2 = new Date ( d1 );
  d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes() + timedelay );
  document.cookie=itemid + "=" + itemid; + 'expires=' + d2 + '; path=/';
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've lost one `;`:

```
document.cookie=itemid + "=" + itemid + ';expires=' + d2 + '; path=/';
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax seem to be wrong

try

```
  document.cookie=itemid + "=" + itemid + ';expires=' + d2 + '; path=/';
```